# Post form data axios in nodejs

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data

I try to post form data using Axios.

This is my code

```
const mydata = new FormData();
mydata.append("id", "4d2f9262-e578-4290-97d3-43303fffbf56");
mydata.append("filter", 2);

axios
  .post("https://www.lalal.ai/api/preview/", mydata, {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

But I get an error like this

```
(node:54756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (D:\reactjs\upload_lalal\server\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (D:\reactjs\upload_lalal\server\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\reactjs\upload_lalal\server\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:244:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:54756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:54756) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can someone explain to me why that is error and how to fix it?

Comment: This is CORS error. You have to give a permission on server side backend..
Use cors module. It is easy if you use express.js for your backend.

Comment: it's not cors bro @ArtemMedianyk

Comment: Its a validation error. If it has a message in body, you can try to solve by reading the error message contained in body. But 403 is a permission error.

Answer (score 0):

Add a catch block to your promise structure.  It's not the root problem, but that error information that's being lost in the promise pipeline is going to be very valuable to your troubleshooting efforts.

Even if you just log your error message you'll learn a bit more about what's happening.

something like:

```
// You already have this...
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
})
// Add this part
.catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
});
```

The error you are currently seeing is letting you know that you need to handle error responses in your promise structures.

It could be something as easy as a 404, where you may have a typo in the address you're after.

**Update Edit**
I noticed that in the unhandled promise rejection messaged, it says error 403.  I can't remember if that's some sort of automatic business that happens in the background in this situation, or if you are actually receiving a forbidden response from the site you are trying to access.

But either way you'll almost certainly see more information if you properly handle the promise with a catch block and console.log the error message.